# Problems with home-brew web crawler

Tags: c++, web-applications

I have built a webcrawler in C++.  I am using an API called `URLdownloadToFile()`.

1. Is there any other API that can be used?
2. The API `URLdownloadToFile()` is working well for some URLs and it is not working well for some other URLs? Please suggest some ways I can overcome this problem?

Thanks,
Dnyaneshwari C.

Comment: We need a lot more detail - which URLs is it not working on, and what is the issue you're seeing with those URLs?

Comment: There is absolutely no way anyone can help you without either (a) you providing more information, or (b) reading your mind to extract said information. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into libcurl which should allow you to pull content using a variety of protocols. This should also support proxies etc which might be what is giving you problems with specific urls. See also; http://curl.haxx.se/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [WinINet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385483(VS.85).aspx) which is a simple C API for high-level interface with the HTTP network stack. Another option is [WinHttp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384252(VS.85).aspx) which is somewhat more compilcated and requires you do deal with COM.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a particular reason for sticking with c++ you could well be better off switching to Python and using [BeautifulSoup](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup). I've used curl, and it is nice, but all my web stuff is done in Python now